# IntentService won't start using AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I know there is a lot of questions about this but I really don't know where is my mistake.

My service is registered in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.app" >
        ...
        <service android:name="com.example.android.app.ScheduledService">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My service extends IntentService

```
public class ScheduledService extends IntentService {
    public ScheduledService() {
        super("ScheduledService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "I ran!");
    }
}
```

My Activity starts the service

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Setting alarm!!");

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, com.example.android.app.ScheduledService.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                        10 * 1000, pending);
    }
}
```

I don't see any exception in the logs. Is there something else I should do to setup my alarm?

Comment: does your service  reschedule itself after application is killed? m curious

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)), `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` is used to retrieve a `PendingIntent` that will perform a broadcast, like calling `Context.sendBroadcast()`.

You need to call `PendingIntent.getService()` instead, which will start `IntentService`:

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Argh, Thanks. Although I feel kinda embarassed for not noticing this.

Comment: Should the fourth parameter be always set to 0 for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at the `AlarmManager` API and the `PendingIntent`.  The `AlarmManager.set()` API is expecting a broadcast intent, which you are providing.  However, you're trying to send a broadcast intent to a service, which cannot be done.  Just create a `BroadcastReceiver` to catch the `Intent` and your BR should then start your service.

Answer (score 2):

The API says:

> typically comes from IntentSender.getBroadcast().

that means `PendingIntent.getService` can work too.
I tested it, and it works.